# JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit SpaceTree node order

Tags: javascript, infovis, thejit, space-tree

I am using the InfoVis SpaceTree to visualize a tree. The complete tree is loaded in one call to the loadJSON method. Each node's children are already in the correct order. But the nodes do not display in the order they are defined in the data structure, i.e. according to their array index.

How can I make them display in the right order? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you solve that? please share your solution

Comment: Share your code and data.

Answer (score 0):

The tree does not display nodes based on their order in the JSON data structure / array index.

Instead, it is based on the 'id' attribute, which is used as the key for storing nodes in an internal hash (well, technically an object). Note it is a hash and *not* an array, so the order is irrelevant.

A node with id 100 will *always* be displayed before a node with id 101. If you want your node's children to display in a particular order, make sure your child nodes are sorted by id.